# cPanel update deleted my email accounts. Is that even possible?

Tags: email, dedicated-server

Like many of you, I noticed a pretty new cPanel login interface today upon accessing my dedicated server. Great, I love new interfaces!

Upon going to check my email accounts, I noticed that they were non existent. As in, an email account I have had setup for many months and have many customers emailing me constantly has disappeared. No trace of it inside cPanel.

What could be the cause of this?

Is it possible to retrieve it?

How can I stop cPanel from updating automatically? I will never update their software again if this is a possibility.

EDIT: Upon further inspection, it seems that whatever javascript cPanel added doesn't jive well with my recently updated firefox 12.0 web browser. I haven't checked any other browsers yet, but after clicking "show less javascript" at the bottom of the emails page inside cPanel I was able to get to an email login screen for the "deleted" email account I was looking for in the first place. PHEW! Hope this helps somebody in the future.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost 99.9% certain cPanel did not delete your email messages. Last upgrade (one or two days ago) missed some .js files, so in order to fix this issue update cPanel manually:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/upcp --force
```

It's no recommended but you can prevent further updates through "Update Preferences" on WHM.

Answer (score 1):

While you may have solved it, your question implies you don't actually have backups of your email. If it's that important to you, you really need to setup backups, and test restoring it.  If it's not backed up, and your server dies, there's really no recovering it.

You do *not* want to try to stop cPanel from updating.  In most circumstances, cPanel is directly exposed to the internet.  You don't want to have something like that running an old version of code.  What happens if there's a security vulnerability in it?

Comment: Thank you for the kind advice. It's not a direct answer to the question posed so I couldn't mark it correct, but you get my upvote. Thank you. I will heed your advice.